# how to retrieve entire row data from datarow based on one column value

Tags: c#

I am new in C#.. struggling to learn it.. I want to know how can I retrieve entire row data based on one column value in datarow.. Let me be clear by giving an example..

```
MerchantNo  TerminalNum CardType  Date
110033445   770010449    Amex    5/09/2011
```

Now I want to retrieve this row based on merchant number and then insert it into sql table..

What I am thinking is:

```
if(MerchantNo!="")
 then retrieve the row
       and insert data in sql table..
```

Actually I am working on importing excel file..Hope u understood my question

```
    string Mno = "";
           foreach (DataRow rowExcel in dtExcel.Rows)
           {

               foreach (DataColumn colExcel in dtExcel.Columns)
               {
                   Mno = rowExcel[colExcel].ToString().Trim();
                   if (Mno != "")
                   {
                       string Mno1 = Mno.Substring(16, 10);
                       Mno =Mno1.ToString();
                       //Int32 MerchNo = Convert.ToInt32(Mno);
                   }
                   break;
               }
               if(Mno!="")// Mno contains the exact MerchantNo.
               {


               }

               //break;

           }
```

Comment: From where do you retrieve the row? A GridView or a DataRow
 or something else?

Comment: Sorry for late response..i want to retrieve the row from DataRow.. I am having a datatable filled with this kind of data..

Answer (score 0):

```
//check if MerchantNo column is neither null nor empty
//r is an object of DataRow
if (Convert.IsDBNull(r["MerchantNo"]) == false && r["MerchantNo"].ToString().Trim() != String.Empty)
{
      //Build an Sql Insert statement based on the data or row
      string strSql = String.Format("INSERT INTO SOMETABLE(X,Y,Z) VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}');", r["colName1"], r["colName2"], r["colName3"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Waqas said, but with added foreah loop for clarification:

```
int MerchNo = 0;
foreach (DataRow r in dtExcel.Rows)
{
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(r["MerchantNo"].ToString().Trim()) &&
       Int32.TryParse(r["MerchantNo"].ToString().Trim(), out MerchNo))
   {
      string strSql = String.Format("INSERT INTO SomeTable(MerchantNo, TerminalNum, CardType, Date) VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}');", r["MerchantNo"], r["TerminalNum"], r["CardType"], r["Date"]);

      SqlCommand scInsertCommand = new SqlCommand(strSql);

      //do transacion and connection assignment, and error handling

      scInsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```